# Can I reset my characters' AI Personalities?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I recently started playing Divinity: Original Sin without really knowing what I was getting myself into. I didn't know what AI Personality did, so I kind of just picked something that sounded good.

However, after having to restart on an easier difficulty, I apparently set my second party member's AI Personality differently than the previous time, as their response to the same dialogue option in the same conversation the second time around was different and ended up influencing a non-beneficial stat for that character. I'd like to change their AI Personality, because the dialogue I've been hearing so far really doesn't suit the character I had in mind.

Is there a way for me to reassign my party members' AI Personality without starting the game over (again)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, by doing so:

> The portal you open after the hall of heroes in the homestead has a
>   magic mirror you can use to redo (primarily) the cosmetic aspects of
>   character creation, including the AI personality.

Sources:

- [On Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/672174-divinity-original-sin/69653561)
- [On official forums](http://larian.com/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=560065)

**Edit:** It is possible to access the mirror after getting a 3rd stone. Source is the last message on [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/672174-divinity-original-sin/69653561) site.

Comment: Do you have any estimate on how far in the game that is?

Comment: @Vemonus I think the Hall of Heroes unlocks after you find two stones and take them to the end of time. Presumably the room after that unlocks after 3 or maybe 4.

Comment: @V4karian you misspelled my name so I didn't get pinged for your comment, but since your answer was updated, I accepted